# The limit of $ m\int_{a}^{1/m} \frac{dx}{x}=0 $ and $ m\int_{a}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{x^{1+m}}=0$ as $m\to0$

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, logarithms, improper-integrals

Given $ a >0 $ is it correct that 
$$ \lim_{m\to 0}m\int_{a}^{1/m} \frac{dx}{x}=0 $$ 
by the properties of the logarithm function?

Or on the other hand, 
$$\lim_{m\to 0} m\int_{a}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{x^{1+m}}=0$$

Do both of these hold because $ x\log(x)\to 0 $ as $x \to 0 $?

Comment: We are computing the limits as what approaches what? It would help if that were clearly indicated.

Comment: $ m \to 0 4 sorry i forgot

Answer (score 1):

We need to be careful. Neither integral exists if $m\lt 0$. But it does make sense to compute the limits as $m$ approaches $0$ from the right.

We look for example at
$$\lim_{m\to 0^+} m\int_a^\infty \frac{dx}{x^{1+m}}.$$
Calculate. The integral is equal to $\frac{1}{m} a^{-m}$. So we want
$$\lim_{m\to 0^+} a^{-m}.$$
This limit is $1$.

For the first problem, again, for positive $m$ we integrate. We want to calculate
$$\lim_{m\to 0^+} m(\ln(1/m)-\ln(a)).$$
Equivalently, we want
$$\lim_{m\to 0^+}(-m)(\ln m +\ln a).$$
By the result you quoted, the limit is $0$.

Comment: so the limit itself does not exist ?

Comment: Limit from the right exists. The full limit does not. Saying $\lim_{m\to 0}$ may be a mistake for $\lim_{m\to 0^+}$. People are sometimes sloppy about such things.